# how to create a temp file from a base64 string

Tags: javascript, perl

im trying to upload an image (base64 string) gotten from a canvas element using javascripts .toDataURL() method:

```
var cropped_base64 = $crop_canvas[0].toDataURL('image/jpeg');
cropped_base64 = cropped_base64.replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,','');

$.ajax({
    url:the_url,
    data:{
        base64_string: cropped_base64
    },
    type:'POST',
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data)
    },
    error:function(data){
        console.log(data)
    }
});
```

and my server side code decodes it:

```
my $base64_string = param('base64_string')
    or return 'error no base 64';

my $image_decoded = MIME::Base64::decode_base64($base64_string)
    or return 'error couldnt decode base64';
```

I need this image as a temporary file, to pass to another routine.

how can I generate this? I cant install modules like Image::magick...

Comment: Just create a file with random filename and save it in /tmp/ folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the decoded content in a scalar. Print that scalar to a file:

```
open ( my $image, '>:raw', '/path/to/image.png' ) or die $!;
print {$image} $image_decoded;
close ( $image );
```

If you want to avoid potential race conditions with it, you'll have to do something about unique-naming. [`File::Temp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Temp.html) is probably a good way to approach this.

E.g.:

```
use File::Temp qw/ tempfile /;
my ( $output_fh, $filename ) =  tempfile();
binmode $output_fh;
print {$output_fh} $image_decoded;
```

This won't auto-delete, because you asked for a filename (which you can then pass on to something else).